# I can not get my IF command to work that wil clear the UILabel if there is nothing in a UITextField

Tags: ios, ipad, uitextfield, uilabel

I have got an iPad app with this as part of my code:

```
if (NAME1.text == @"") {
    SS1.text = @"";
    SPA1.text = @"";
}
```

But it does not clear the `UILabel` if there is nothing in a `UITextField`!

Does anyone know how I can get it to do what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the `length` of the string, don't do direct pointer comparison:

```
if ([NAME1.text length] == 0) {
    SS1.text = @"";
    SPA1.text = @"";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Should it be:

If ([NAME1.text isEqualToString:@""])